# Image captch is not reloaded when user enter wrong captch

Tags: 7, ajax, captcha

So in my project contact us form is there . In that I used image captch. But problem is there when user insert wrong captch then ajax throw error message but after that image captcha is not reloaded. For reloading captch require refresh whole page .So then user also try to insert captch once again then also throw error. So for that mean for reloading image captch what should I do.. ? please help me I am stuck on that issues...

Comment: which module you use for captcha?

Comment: captch and image captch module..!!